# Shopping cart component not updating with correct quantities

Tags: reactjs

when I increment single card and click add button the card or cards is successfully added to the shopping cart but when I increment two or three cards first and then click the add button the respective card item quantity count does not match with the incremented values.

the full code is here -https://github.com/sivadass/react-shopping-cart

I think the problem is in Counter.js, it's not setting the previous state when increment and add later to the shopping card

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class Counter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: this.props.productQuantity };
    this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
    this.decrement = this.decrement.bind(this);
  }

  increment(e) {
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({
        value: Number(prevState.value) + 1
      }),
      function() {
        this.props.updateQuantity(this.state.value);
      }
    );
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  decrement(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.value <= 1) {
      return this.state.value;
    } else {
      this.setState(
        prevState => ({
          value: Number(prevState.value) - 1
        }),
        function() {
          this.props.updateQuantity(this.state.value);
        }
      );
    }
  }

  feed(e) {
    this.setState(
      {
        value: this.refs.feedQty.value
      },
      function() {
        this.props.updateQuantity(this.state.value);
      }
    );
  }

  resetQuantity() {
    this.setState({
      value: 1
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="stepper-input">
        <a href="#" className="decrement" onClick={this.decrement}>
          –
        </a>
        <input
          ref="feedQty"
          type="number"
          className="quantity"
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.feed.bind(this)}
        />
        <a href="#" className="increment" onClick={this.increment}>
          +
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Counter.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.number
};

export default Counter;
```

Comment: https://sivadass.github.io/react-shopping-cart/

Comment: You change the quantity at the top level in `index.js` and pass it as props to every `Product`. You will need to remove it and handle the `quantity` for every `Product` independently.

Comment: Counter should be handled at Fruit level. It seems if you increment on one item and then add a different item which was not incremented, you are getting the incremented amount of that item.

Comment: @dasitha I just provided you an answer after cloning your repo. Your feature works as expected with the changes I added. Let me know if that works for you. :)

Comment: @ChristopherNgo thanks.. I will check and let you know

Comment: @ChristopherNgo thank you very much, bro... its working fine now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your components are all consuming the same quantity value stored in the parent via `index.js`. Your shopping cart takes the last-updated count value from any `Counter` and uses that to add the selected item. You need to isolate the quantity/count for each `Product`.

I cloned your repo and I was able to fix this by making an update to the `Product.js` component.

I gave `Product.js` its own private quantity to keep track of

```
class Product extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedProduct: {},
      quickViewProdcut: {},
      quantity: 1,
      isAdded: false
    };

    this.updateQuantity = this.updateQuantity.bind(this)
  }
```

Create an event-handler that would update its own state-quantity.

```
  updateQuantity(value){
    this.setState({
      quantity: value
    })
  }
```

Update definition of `quantity` in `render()` to use our isolated state-value instead of the value stored in the parent.

```
let quantity = this.state.quantity;
```

Pass the event-handler above as a prop to Counter

```
 <Counter
  productQuantity={quantity}
  updateQuantity={this.updateQuantity}
  resetQuantity={this.resetQuantity}
/>
```

Your feature works completely fine after integrating those changes. See below for full-code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Counter from "./Counter";

class Product extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedProduct: {},
      quickViewProdcut: {},
      quantity: 1,
      isAdded: false
    };

    this.updateQuantity = this.updateQuantity.bind(this)
  }

  updateQuantity(value){
    this.setState({
      quantity: value
    })
  }

  addToCart(image, name, price, id, quantity) {
    this.setState(
      {
        selectedProduct: {
          image: image,
          name: name,
          price: price,
          id: id,
          quantity: quantity
        }
      },
      function() {
        this.props.addToCart(this.state.selectedProduct);
      }
    );
    this.setState(
      {
        isAdded: true
      },
      function() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({
            isAdded: false,
            selectedProduct: {}
          });
        }, 3500);
      }
    );
  }
  quickView(image, name, price, id) {
    this.setState(
      {
        quickViewProdcut: {
          image: image,
          name: name,
          price: price,
          id: id
        }
      },
      function() {
        this.props.openModal(this.state.quickViewProdcut);
      }
    );
  }
  render() {
    let image = this.props.image;
    let name = this.props.name;
    let price = this.props.price;
    let id = this.props.id;
    let quantity = this.state.quantity;
    return (
      <div className="product">
        <div className="product-image">
          <img
            src={image}
            alt={this.props.name}
            onClick={this.quickView.bind(
              this,
              image,
              name,
              price,
              id,
              quantity
            )}
          />
        </div>
        <h4 className="product-name">{this.props.name}</h4>
        <p className="product-price">{this.props.price}</p>
        <Counter
          productQuantity={quantity}
          updateQuantity={this.updateQuantity}
          resetQuantity={this.resetQuantity}
        />
        <div className="product-action">
          <button
            className={!this.state.isAdded ? "" : "added"}
            type="button"
            onClick={this.addToCart.bind(
              this,
              image,
              name,
              price,
              id,
              quantity
            )}
          >
            {!this.state.isAdded ? "ADD TO CART" : "✔ ADDED"}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Product;
```